# Postgres createuser command not found after installing with homebrew on my Mac

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, hl7-fhir, createuser

`lawn-128-61-59-74:~ postgres$ createuser -R  -P -S  -D fhir`

After running "brew install postgresql" and running postgres, when running the above command I am getting the following error:

"-bash: createuser: command not found"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

run:

```
 sudo find / -name createuser
```

This will find where the `createuser` command is located on your machine. Add what you find to your path.

Comment: What will this accomplish?

Comment: Specifically this helped find the path to the createuser command, which allowed my to run the createuser command manually afterwards. (specifically "/usr/local/bin/createuser postgres", which sometimes is "/opt/homebrew/bin/createuser postgres").

Answer (score 5):

**This probably means that Postgres is not in your `PATH`.**

Since you installed with Homebrew, your `PATH` should include

```
Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin
```

You can add this line to your `.bash_profile` to fix that

```
export PATH="Applications/Postres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin:$PATH"
```

*(Note: `9.6` is the version -- this may be different for you.)*

---

If you didn't use `brew` to install Postgres you can use Vao Tsun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43272285/5369466) to find where Postgres is on your machine, and add that to your path instead

Comment: You have a typo, should be: `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin:$PATH"`

Missing a g in postgres.

Comment: This path is for Postgres installed with Postgres.app. If you installed with Homebrew, it'll look more like `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.20/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

From your console/putty/shell you can connect to PgSQL running:

```
su - postgres -c "psql"
```

then you can run/execute yours commands/QUERYS...

```
CREATE USER synapse;
ALTER USER synapse WITH ENCRYPTED password 'I-love-Stackoverflow.com-xD';
CREATE DATABASE synapse ENCODING 'UTF-8' LC_COLLATE='en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE='en_US.UTF-8' template=template0 OWNER synapse;
```

if you have some trouble, then first try creating a ROLE:

```
CREATE ROLE synapse;
DROP ROLE synapse;
```

and after you can CREATE users...

Regards